# Como puedo utilizar print

Tags: python

**Estoy** haciendo una tarea, y me pidieron hacer una pregunta. Me pueden apoyar por favor.
Me podrían explicar como puedo crear cualquier ejercicio con **print**

Comment: print sierve para mostrar cosas por consola, puedes hacer `print("hola")`, `print(20)`, `print(obj)` esto te dara una representacion grafico de lo que le pongas

Answer (score 2):

El script que debes hacer para comenzar con python debiera lucir como este:

```
print("¡Hola mundo!")
```

Si lo ejecutas, va a producir la salida:

```
¡Hola mundo!
```

La [función *print()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) sirve para escribir a archivos de texto, como la salida estándar del programa. Le puedes pasar cualquier número de argumentos, separados por coma y de los tipos más variados.

Por ejemplo:

```
saludo = "¡Hola mundo!"
entero = 7
print(saludo, entero)
```

Va a producir una salida como esta:

```
¡Hola mundo! 7
```

Según la documentación enlazada su definición es:

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

Esto significa que la función puede recibir estos parámetros *especiales*:

- `sep`, recibe una cadena, y usará esa cadena como separador entre todos los argumentos que se le hayan pasado, ejemplo: `print("hola", "mundo", sep=",")`
- `end`, recibe una cadena, utiliza esa cadena al terminar de *imprimir* todos los argumentos, por ejemplo: `print("hola", "mundo", sep=",", end='<->')`
- `file` es el archivo a donde escribir (en realidad un *text stream file*). Por defecto es la salida estándar, si quieres escribir a otro archivo: print("hola", file=miArchivo)`
- `flush` obliga a hacer *flush* del archivo, si este maneja *buffers*.

Encontrarás más información en la documentación.

Comment: Me ganaste, iba a publicar algo parecido

Comment: Tuve suerte, hoy estoy más desconectado que otras veces... :p

Answer (score 0):

Amigo para preguntar algo a un usuario escribes:

```
print ('la pregunta')
```

y listo! si quieres almacenar la respuesta:

```
respuesta = 'texto'
respuesta = input('cómo te llamas?')
#saldra un mensaje preguntando 'cómo te llamas?' y digamos que escribes 'sebas'
print = ('tu nombre es: ',respuesta)
```

y listo!

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución! Pero tu respuesta tiene algunos problemas lógicos (no tengo intención de ofender, perdón si ofendo). Primero, print no sirve para "preguntarle algo" al usuario, para eso usas input (que es lo que haces más abajo). Segundo, en tu ultimo código de ejemplo pones `print = ('tu nombre es: ',respuesta)`. Esta expresión lo que hace es guardar la tupla `('tu nombre es: ',respuesta)` en la variable print. No querras haber dicho lo mismo pero sin el =?